# nohup in "bash script -s ..." do NOT return prompt

Tags: bash, nohup

I'm using bash to upload springboot package and restart it, but commands do NOT return prompt.

restart.sh:

```
kill -9 $(lsof -t -i:10001) \
&& nohup java -jar /path/to/app-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar --server.port=10001 >/dev/null 2>&1 </dev/null &
```

then I run the command:

```
ssh root@ip "bash -s" < restart.sh
```

it does NOT return prompt.

Comment: can you try adding an "&" to the end of restart.sh. something like ssh root@ip "bash -s" < restart.sh &

Comment: Awesome. :) glad it worked. Also please close the question if it resolved

Answer (score 0):

Adding & at the end of restart.sh worked. Comments above